# Return Value from time.strptime()

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, strptime

I am using `t = time.strptime()` in my Python program and want to check if it fails to return a valid structure.

When I was programming in C I used to check for a return value of NULL to indicate that an invalid call had been made. However this does not seem to work in Python. I have also checked for `not t` and `-1`. What I am trying to do at this stage is check that the user has not put in an invalid datetime without checking each field individually for errors like 31/02/2014, etc.

How can I check the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses [*exceptions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) to communicate incorrect inputs. If `time.strptime()` doesn't raise an exception, the return value is correct and you don't have to validate it yourself.

If an exception is raised, you can catch it with a `try...except` statement:

```
try:
    t = time.strptime(userinput, format)
except ValueError:
    # exception raised, not valid input, give feedback to user
```

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime('01/02/2014 10:42:36', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=10, tm_min=42, tm_sec=36, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=32, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strptime('31/02/2014 10:42:36', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 494, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/Users/mpietre/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 465, in _strptime
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Note that the exception was thrown here because `31` falls outside the range valid days for February.

Comment: Looked in two Python books and NOT documented. Problem fixed now!